# delete query is correct, but can't delete

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a PHP code piece that would update and delete admin data in same page. My update query is fine, and my delete query is correct, except that it can't delete the data when Delete button is pressed.
Code:

```
<?php
    require("connect.inc");
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['update_admin'])){
        $id = $_POST['admin_id'];
        $pass = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['admin_pass'])));
        $name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['admin_name'])));

        $up_ad = "update admins set a_name = '$name', a_pass = '$pass' where a_id = '$id'";
        mysql_query($up_ad);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['deladmin'])){
        mysql_query("delete from admins where a_id = '$_POST[admin_id]'");
    }

    $admin_sql = "select * from admins order by a_name";
    $adminres = mysql_query($admin_sql);

    echo "
    <table border = 1>
        <tr>
            <td>Admin ID</td>
            <td>Admin Name</td>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td colspan = 3>Options</td>
        </tr>
    "; 
    while($admin_rows = mysql_fetch_array($adminres)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <form action = 'editdel_admin.php' method = post>
                <td><?php echo $admin_rows['a_id'] ?></td>
                <td><input type = text name = 'admin_name' placeholder = 'Type here' value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($admin_rows['a_name']); ?>" required></td>
                <td><input type = text name = 'admin_pass' placeholder = 'Maximum of 25 characters' maxlength = '25' value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($admin_rows['a_pass']); ?>" required></td>
                <?php 
                echo "
                <td><input type = hidden name = 'admin_id' value = ".$admin_rows['a_id']."></td>
                <td><input type = submit name = 'update_admin' value = 'Edit'></td>
                <td><input type = submit name = 'deladmin' value = 'Delete'></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    ";
    }
    echo "
    </table>";
?>
```

Comment: you already set `$id` to `$_POST['admin_id']`, try this `mysql_query("delete from admins where a_id = '$id'");
`

Comment: OT: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars` when storing the username and password? That should only be used when displaying text on a web page.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this script I don't know where to begin. Injection Overload! I really hope this is not a professional piece of work!

Comment: Is id stored as a string?

Comment: @anurupr He only sets that variable when you click on the `Edit` button, not the `Delete` button.

Comment: Are you sure the `DELETE` query is correct? You're not checking for errors after it.

Comment: Add `or die(mysql_error())` after all the calls to `mysql_query()`, so you'll see error messages if they fail.

Comment: i'm only just practicing, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if the user has the permission to delete record in database.

Change delete query to

```
"delete from admins where a_id = '" . $_POST['admin_id'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("delete from admins where a_id = '".$_POST['admin_id']."'");
```

instead of

```
mysql_query("delete from admins where a_id = '$_POST[admin_id]'");
```

Comment: `'".  intval($_POST[admin_id]) . "'` to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You mistaken in this line

```
 mysql_query("delete from admins where a_id = '$_POST[admin_id]'");
```

`$_POST[admin_id]` here the key value is not specified correctly. It must be like this 
  `$_POST['admin_id']`. And in embedded strings user parenthesis to avoid greedy method string replace. Changing you code like this will fixed your problem

```
   mysql_query("delete from admins where a_id = '{$_POST['admin_id']}'");
```

**Beware that mysql_* methods are deprecated and insecure instead use mysqli_* or pdo methods**